# C# EditableValue<T> implementation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm looking for ready-to-use implementation of common problem - to get information about property like : has changed, initial value etc.

I'm pretty sure I saw something like this already done, but I could not find it.

I'm thinking about something like this:

```
public EditableValue<string> Name;
```

and then usage:

```
if(Name.HasChanged)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name.NewValue))
        Name.DiscardChanged();
}
```

Do you know any solutions for this?

I'm creating project based on WPF and MVVM.

Comment: what is ready to use implementation ? people here would try to improvise your code ..

Comment: Point for you but... this is just reinventing the wheel twice.

Comment: its not, its to learn how wheel works in first place then to use it..

Comment: Are you thinking of the entity framework? (Specifically EntityObject?)

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer I'm thinking about something like this, but available to use without Entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once had a similar need and wrote a class, which looks like this:

```
public class EditableValue<T> : BindableBase where T : struct
{
    private T _value;
    private T? _displayValue;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Value);
        }
    }

    public T DisplayValue
    {
        get { return _displayValue ?? Value; }
        set
        {
            _displayValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => DisplayValue);
        }
    }

    public bool HasChanges
    {
        get { return _displayValue.HasValue; }
    }

    public void DiscardChanges()
    {
        _displayValue = null;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => DisplayValue);
    }

    public void ApplyChanges()
    {
        Value = DisplayValue;
        OnPropertyChanged(() => DisplayValue);
        OnPropertyChanged(() => Value);
    }
}
```

Note, that it uses BindableBase from the [Prism.Mvvm nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Mvvm) to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Binding just to `DisplayValue` gives you the ability to change values in the UI and by clicking save (or discard) you can set `Value` (or reset `DisplayValue`).
As long as there's nothing set for `_displayValue` the actual value will be passed through.
You can also bind to `Value` if you're only interested in the actual value without outstanding changes.

Comment: This is kind of solution what I have right now. Why your T can be struct only?

Comment: T has to be struct (which includes any value type), because I use a nullable field for _displayValue and this wouldn't be possible for reference types in this way. This could be improved but I just used the class with value types.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try implementing  `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `EditableValue` class and then listen to property changed event.

If you try share your code and then we might be able to fix any issues that you might have.